# How should it be explained to Christians that miracles no longer happen?

Tags: christianity, miracles

As Muslims, we believe that miracles ended with the prophet and that the last miracles were with our prophet Mohammad.  It is, however a common Christian belief that miracles continue to happen in our time.

A Christian friend once sent me [a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_Soufanieh) with claims of a modern-day miracle, saying that some wounds appear on a girl's body every year with no scientific explanation.

Presumably, scientific knowledge is still unable to explain her case; this does not, however, mean that it is a miracle.  There is a significant difference between this sort of incident (which may appear miraculous, but is likely just not scientifically understood yet) and the true miracles of the prophet.  How, then, can we explain to the Christians that this sort of thing is not and cannot be a miracle, since miracles ended with our prophet?

Comment: No miracles do happen , its a Muslim beleif

Comment: May I know which school of thought has this belief " miracles ended with the prophet "as I myself have heard such claims many times?

Comment: @UmarAdeel check this wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_view_of_miracles

Answer (score 2):

First of all, no we don't believe that miracles ended with the prophet. Who said that? You don't even need a prophet to have a miracle.

In fact, Quoting wikipedia:

> A miracle is an event not ascribable to human power or the laws of nature and consequently attributed to a supernatural, especially divine, agency. Such an event may be attributed to a miracle worker, saint, or faith based leader. A miracle is when a being with supernatural powers, such as a god, works with the laws of nature to perform what are miracles.Theologians say that, with divine providence, theistic gods regularly work through created nature yet are free to work without, above, or against it as well

As you see Allah can make a miracle, and it isn't about prophets only. Miracles can happen with you as a person if Allah chooses to make such miracle.

Answer (score 0):

Miracles are happening everyday around us, in our world. For example when a plane crashes and there is one or even more survivors, that is a miracle. When a car accident happens everybody dies and a little child is still alive, that is a miracle. When they find a live person under a demolished house (because of earth quake), after some days, that is miracle.

So miracle could happen any time and any where and that is all God's will.

Comment: well then you have to give me your definition of miracle @user5053 ... what you are talking about is not miracle. prophets are the only people who can make miracles and such miracles are not naturally

Comment: i believe that miracle is anything out of human's control. something that God wants to happen. even with the prophet and in their time all miracles happened because God wanted them to happen. therefore, anything that happens only by God order could be a miracle. so my definition of miracle is anything that God wants to happen and no one else is able to do it by any power(like curing a disabled).